# Clustering of energy data, Pre-Clustering / Leveling Options?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, transpose

I get energy data from 15 locations. In total its 3 features (distorsion value for L1, L2, L3), so I have 90 Values for every 10 minutes.

| Date | Loc1_D_L1 | Loc1_D_L2 | Loc1_D_L3 | Loc2_D_L1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 10,387 | 12,953 | 9,563 | 11,938 |
| 2021-02-01 00:10:00 | .... | .... | .... | .... |

I hope the idea is clear.

Now I want to cluster them, but in terms of time but in terms of location. I want to group them if possible. For example: Locations 3,4,5,7 behave similar = Cluster 1. Location 1,2,9 Behave similar = Cluster 2. I want to derive if its feasible just to observe the behaviour of certrain Locactions to reduce the complexity for other operations.

So I did transpone the matrix and applied KMeans Clustering

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from pandas import DataFrame

model = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(df)
pred = model.labels_
pred

Nc = range(1, 20)
kmeans = [KMeans(n_clusters=i) for i in Nc]
kmeans
score = [kmeans[i].fit(df).score(df) for i in range(len(kmeans))]
score
df['Cluster']=pred
```

I end up with a table, that looks like this:

| Date | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 2021-02-01 00:10:00 | ... | Cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Loc1_D_L1 | 10,387 | 12,953 | ... | 1 |
| Loc1_D_L2 | 12,963 | 10,xzy | ... | 1 |
| Loc1_D_L3 | 10,387 | 12,953 | ... | 2 |
| Loc1_D_L1 | 12,963 | 10,xzy | ... | 1 |

The problem is:
It now clusters every feature but not every Location. Its not helpful to cluster L1 of Location 1 with L1 of Location 3.

How to solve this? Is there a "level" function or can I control it via if / else statements that refer to the string in the first column?

Any other ideas, strategies or doubts?

Answer (score 0):

Any ideas? My solution for now:
I tried to rise the number of clusters so that the described problem does not occur. 6 clusters do the job, but that is not a clean solution.

Next step would be to measure the "distance" of the clusters.
What could be an decent tool for doing this?
The "Kullback–Leibler divergence" could be an option. If I understand it correctly, this is designed for probabilites that add up to one, so its possibly not the correct tool.
How else to challenge or measure the qualitity of my clusters? Plotting is fine, but more a qualitative approach.